# Is there any library for javascript to read .cer file and get key from it?

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I want to encrypt data on client side and web application take .cer file from user local computer. After take I will use keys to encrypt data but I want to library or any way to read .cer file I searched on the internet and I do not find anything library. I use Public-key cryptography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to do this you need to break out of the sandbox that is the users browser. The "normal" way to do this is to create a signed applet. The user needs to have Java correctly configured on his computer and needs to verify that the signed applet can run. Then this Applet can use it's file reading permissions to access files on the users computer, and the JavaScript can use the applet to read the certificate (and to perform the encryption).

Now, although this is possible in principle, I would really, *really*, **really**, ***really*** advice you not to go this way. This advice comes from somebody who did implement such a solution and just made very sure that other projects do not use the same solution.

You should use TLS, possibly with client authentication as others have suggested. If you want you may always send a public key over the trusted TLS transmission and let your JavaScript use that key to encrypt data. In general though a well configured TLS connection should be enough.

Comment: Why do you advice me not to go this way?What problems can occur?

Comment: Not all browsers l have the same functionality. Same goes for the Java system. You will have a myriad of systems to test, and updates are not likely controlled by you. Many browsers don't even support Java applets anymore. Have a look at l the systems stuck on IE6, even banking systems that are supposed to be secure. Finally, you will have to worry about the HTML, the JavaScript, the Java and the server component...

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to understand **why** exactly do you want to read those keys but depending on what are you trying to achieve you may use [Client-authenticated TLS handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake) and the browser will take care of handling the keys for you. If all you need is encrypting some data during the transport then maybe even [Simple TLS handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Simple_TLS_handshake) would be enough for you. Read [JavaScript Cryptography Considered Harmful](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) and make sure that you are not trying to reinvent something that already works in a more standard way.

Answer (score 1):

For browser security reasons, Javascript in a browser cannot access a `.cer` file (or any file for that matter) on the local user's computer.  A key (for use on a single web-site) could be stored in Local Storage instead and accessed from there.

You may want to rethink what you're really trying to do.  If you use https to communicate with your server and your server has appropriate configuration and security credentials, your communication between browser and server will automatically be protected with public/private key cryptography while in transit.

Comment: User will choose .cer file on client side and i want to use this to get key and encrypt data.For all jobs i want to use javascirpt if it is possible.With this i can add one level to security over communication protected

Comment: After selecting the `.cer` file it can be uploaded to your server and you could then retrieve the keys from the server, but that is probably not what you want.  I strongly suspect that if you describe what overall problem you're really trying to solve, there is probably a better approach that is supported by the browser.

Comment: No I won't upload to server just I  get key from it via javascript and encrypt it via javascript also.Any suggestion have you in difference way?

Comment: @mikel - yeah, use SSL to transfer data to your server securely or describe your real problem in more detail so we can offer better solutions.

Comment: I want to make more secure system and make it with client side encryption

Comment: @mikel - SSL is client-side encryption using public key cryptography.  You haven't explained why that built-in and super easy to use mechanism is not plenty sufficient and probably better than anything you can implement in client-side javascript.